# Locally compact vector space over a finite field

Tags: local-fields, topological-vector-spaces

In the wikipedia article titled "topological vector space", there is a line saying the following.

"Let $K$ be a locally compact topological field, for example to real or complex numbers. A topological vector space over $K$ is locally compact if and only if it is finite-dimensional, that is, isomorphic to $K^n$ for some natural number $n$."

I am fine with the real or complex numbers. However, on the one hand if we take a finite field, say $\mathbb{F}_p$ for a prime number $p$, with the discrete topology, it seems to me that $\mathbb{F}_p$ satisfies all conditions of being a locally compact topological field. On the other hand it is well-known that the field $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ is locally compact as well, and it is obviously not a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$. What am I missing? (Maybe one needs to add the condition that $K$ has to be non-discrete as well?) Thanks a lot.

EDIT: As Denis pointed out in the comment, $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ is not equipped with the vector space topology corresponding to $\mathbb{F}_p$ (i.e., the product topology). This answers my question above, but it raises a new question. Note that the quoted wikipedia statement is used in a proof of the classification of local fields to conclude that any local field $F$ containing $\mathbb{Q}_p$ must be an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. How do we know that there is no some other big local field which extends $\mathbb{Q}_p$ but does not carry the "right" vector space topology (product topology), in the same way as $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ extends $\mathbb{F}_p$ but does not carry the right vector space topology?

Comment: The topology you are putting on $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ is not the vector space topology (that is the product topology once you chose a basis).

Comment: @DenisNardin What you said is absolutely right. But my main concern is that people use this statement in the classification of local fields to conclude that the only local fields $F$ containing $\mathbb{Q}_p$ are algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, which seems to only need $F$ to be some extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ that also extends the norm; but surely $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ does the same thing to $\mathbb{F}_p$ as well.

Comment: This statement confuses me too.  Suppose I take $\mathbb{F}_2$ which is a compact topological field.  Then the countable product $\mathbb{F}_2^\omega$, with its product topology, is a topological vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$, isn't it?  But it's compact (it's homeomorphic to Cantor space).  And it's certainly infinite dimensional.  Unless I am missing something, I think that statement might simply be wrong.

Comment: From my viewpoint, "non-discrete" is missing from the (quoted) requirements on the field. If that requirement is added, then everything works out as expected.

Comment: From the Laurent series point of view $\mathbb{F}_p((T))$ sits inside $\mathbb{F}_p^{\mathbb{Z}}$ and inherits its topology from the corresponding product topology. However, this is different from DN's product topology coming from a Hamel (vs Schauder) basis. As NE and PG said the wikipedia statement is just wrong as is.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam No the topology of $F_p((t))$ is not the topology inherited from $F_p^Z$ (the latter is not locally compact).

Comment: @YCor: I don't understand. $\mathbb{F}_p$ is finite and thus compact. The product $\mathbb{F}_p^{\mathbb{Z}}$ is compact by Tychonov's Theorem.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Sure, $F_p^Z$ is compact. Then if you view $F_p((t))$ dense inside, then it's not locally compact for the induced topology. (A non-closed subgroup of a locally compact group is never locally compact for the induced topology.)

Comment: @YCor: You're right, I spoke too fast. I guess the moral of the story is that on $\mathbb{F}_p((T))$ seen as a set of double-sided sequences the metric $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} p^{-n}d(x_n,y_n)$ is not the same as  $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} p^{-|n|}d(x_n,y_n)$ ...:)-

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_p((T))$ is a topological vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$, and is a perfectly good counterexample. Not all topological vector spaces have the product topology.

Comment: I suspect it's good enough for the field to be infinite, and it doesn't have to be non-discrete. The easy counterexamples for finite fields aren't locally compact when they're over an infinite discrete field.